# Open links in Gmail on Chrome in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, gmail, google-chrome-extensions, userscripts

I use Firefox as primary browser, but use Gmail in Chrome.
I'd like all the links in e-mails and chat to open in a new Firefox tab instead of a new Chrome tab, *automatically* (I know copy-paste, drag and drop… !).

I looked for an extension, or an userscript. I didn't find any, and I'm not even sure an userscript in Chrome (with Tapermonkey) can send an open-link event to Firefox.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: A quick search brought up [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-with-external-applic/hccmhjmmfdfncbfpogafcbpaebclgjcp?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon). I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Found it, but I'm looking for something to make it automatic. On click, instead of opening in new tab, open in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

To open a link from Chrome into Firefox, just drag it from Chrome to Firefox tab bar.

Comment: There's plenty of ways to move text from somewhere to somewhere else (drag-and drop, copy-paste)… Ok. The question is about automation : click (and only click) -> open link in Fx ;)

Comment: Do you want links 'only' from Gmail to open in Firefox, or any links from any site on Chrome to open in Firefox?

Comment: First option, Gmail only (but if you find a way to achieve the second one, it sounds a good trail!